# 404 Error with Restler for all Url

Tags: php, restler

I am trying to create a plugin for making an API server for Oxwall framework. I am new to Restler but experienced developer for Oxwall platform.

I get the below error when I access the url.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  },
  "debug": {
    "source": "Routes.php:383 at route stage",
    "stages": {
      "success": [
        "get"
      ],
      "failure": [
        "route",
        "negotiate",
        "message"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Oxwall has its own Routing and MVC methods. Below is how I have defined the route (cmd is just a dummy value to make Oxwall consider it valid for say/* routes)

```
OW::getRouter()->addRoute(new OW_Route('service', 'say/:cmd', "OXWALLAPI_CTRL_Api", 'index'));
```

So now, when I try to access http://www.mysite.com/say/hello it get the above 404 error.

**api.php :**

```
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

class OXWALLAPI_CTRL_Api extends OW_ActionController {

  public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();

       $r = new Restler();
       $r->addAPIClass('Say');
       $r->handle();
   }

   public function index() {

   }

}
```

**Say.php:**

```
class Say {

    function hello($to = 'world') {
       return "Hello $to!";
    }

    function hi($to) {
       return "Hi $to!";
    }

}
```

Oxwall has its own .htaccess file. I have placed the below .htaccess in the plugin folder.

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag display_errors Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Is `Say.php` in the same folder of `index.php`?

Otherwise you should use the following in Say.php class,
if for instance your Say.php is in Test/Say.php
In Say.php write

```
<?php
namespace Test;
use stdClass;
//..... the rest of your class
```

In index.php you'll write

```
$r->addClass('Test\Say');
```

- Did you properly set the `behat.yml` file?

base_url must point to your index.php path

Comment: Both Api.php and Say.php are in same folder. The docs does not say anything about behat.yml configuration. Could you please guide me where can I find that section?

Comment: I understand that behat.yml configuration is only for unit testing.

Comment: Ok I might have missed that, but in your api.php I also don't see `require_once '../../../vendor/restler.php';`

Comment: I have done that. Without that, you will not be getting the above error message.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I would really appreciate an answer.