# Sending http request in oxwall

Tags: php, http, httprequest, oxwall

I  am working on oxwall plugin. I am stuck at one problem .
I need to know how to send http request to url.
For example :

1) In joomla CMS we send request like this,

```
$http = new JHttp($options, $transport);
$response = $http->post($url, $data);
```

2)In drupal ,

```
$options = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'data' => $data,
    'timeout' => 15,
    'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
  );
$result = drupal_http_request($url, $option);
```

I want to know , what is the oxwall way  of doing this task, Please help me or hint me which library  to look out. If i am unable to find the solution  will it be okay to use custom php code send request . Will it affect the performance of plugin ?

Comment: yes , i can use curl , but there must be some oxwall way of doing this .My first priority is using inbuilt function of oxwall. I will use custom php code , if i wont find the way.

Comment: maybe this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813776/404-error-with-restler-for-all-url) post would help

Comment: Any help from oxwall developer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there exists exactly what you are looking for. 
You would just use custom PHP code for this.

Comment: Yes , I have talked to the developer team and found out they havent included the library yet. I used curl functions.